# Back to MainActivity Android App

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I built an app with a Navigation Drawer and a Toolbar. I want to implement that the user can return to the "MainActivity" with clicking on the "lable" of the Toolbar.

**When the following Acivity is running, and the user clicks on the Toolbar it should return him/her to the MainActivity**

```
public class Activity_A extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_angebot_erstellen);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.toolbar) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

**My App_Bar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="blub">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="blubb">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activity_A" />
    <activity android:name=".Activity_E" />
    <activity android:name=".Login" />
    <activity android:name=".Register" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Sorry i am a little bit new to this and the problem is, that nothing happens while clicking no the lable. Thank you for every help.

Best Regards :)

Comment: Do you want to use your Toolbar as your ActionBar ?

Comment: What do you mean with click on the ActionBar?

Comment: I think i want to use my Toolbar as ActionBar then. Sry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you put your `Activity_A` as a child of Main Activity in the `Manifest` ?

```
 <activity
            android:name=".Activity_A"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="blubb.MainActivity"/>
</activity>
```

Comment: I added the Manifest. I dont think so?

Comment: com.abc is the name of my package. In your case, use blubb. See my editted answer for you

Comment: ah this is working fine. :) but isnt there a way to click directly on the android:label="@string/app_name" of the toolbar?